# I want to graph all of ArcSin without restriction, how would I format that?

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I am new to this and I've plotted this:Plot[3 ArcSin[x + 4] - 16, but I don't know what/how to specify the range?

Comment: Something like `ParametricPlot[{Sin[t] - 4, 3 t - 16}, {t, -5, 5}]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
fun = 3 ArcSin[x + 4] - 16;

FunctionDomain[fun, x]
```

> -5 <= x <= -3

```
Plot[fun, {x, -5, -3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment.

Amplifying on the comment by @J.M.

```
Solve[y == 3 ArcSin[x + 4] - 16, x, Reals][[1]]

(*  {x -> ConditionalExpression[-4 + Sin[(16 + y)/3], 
   1/2 (-32 - 3 π) <= y <= 1/2 (-32 + 3 π)]}  *)
```

Or

```
Reduce[y == 3 ArcSin[x + 4] - 16, x, Reals]

(*  1/2 (-32 - 3 π) <= y <= 1/2 (-32 + 3 π) && x == -4 + Sin[(16 + y)/3]  *)
```

Let `t == (16 + y) / 3`, i.e., `y == 3 t - 16` and `x == Sin[t] - 4`

Verifying that the parametric representation is equivalent to the original equation

```
Reduce[
 Eliminate[
  {x == Sin[t] - 4, y == 3 t - 16}, t,
  InverseFunctions -> True],
 y]

(*  y == -16 + 3 ArcSin[4 + x]  *)
```

Since the [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) restricts `y` to `Interval[{-1/2(32+3Pi), 1/2(-32+3Pi)}]`, then `t` is restricted to the interval

```
t == (16 + y)/3 /. 
  y -> Interval[{-1/2 (32 + 3 Pi), 1/2 (-32 + 3 Pi)}] // Simplify

(*  t == Interval[{-(π/2), π/2}]  *)

ParametricPlot[{Sin[t] - 4, 3 t - 16}, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

This is the same result provided by @eldo